# Templates and access

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures

I've read tons of guides of how to use templates effectively, however none seem to answer this question. They all seem to access the nodes inside the class and nothing more.

For example, I have a doubly linked list. The list contains a Node:

```
template<class T>
struct TNode
{
    T Data;
    TNode* pNext;
    TNode* pPrev;
};
```

Now I'm trying to make the data accessible from anywhere, for example:

```
TNode* pNode = m_VertexList.GetFirstElement();
```

However every way I've tried, I end up having to cast it in some way:

```
TNode<CObject*>* pNode = m_VertexList.GetFirstElement<CObject*>();
//I can't remember at this point if this is the exact syntax, but you get the idea
```

Now while this isnt a very big problem, it isn't ideal

Is there a way I can make it so the first line will correctly return the type without having to specify it?

Here is the error I get:

```
1>...error C2955: 'TNode' : use of class template requires template argument list
```

**Here in pastebin is the whole node structure and dllist class:
http://pastebin.com/awkq9rcq**

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The error says you're trying to use TNode without specifying the actual type. For example `TNode<int>` rather than just `TNode`

Comment: sadly none of the tons of guides you read apparently mentioned you could use `std::list<>` and not reinvent the wheel. I concur with billz. I also find the `GetFirstElement` you say works odd, since I would expect the object *type* of `m_VertexList` to be the template-type that seizes a template parameter; not a member function.

Comment: What was wrong with `TNode<CObject *> *pNode = m_VertexList.GetFirstElement();` ? You can use a typedef if you find the left-hand-side ugly.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it, it just gives it the appearance of being less modular than it could be. So it is working, I'm just asking if there is a way to improve myself :)

Answer (score 2):

You would need something like `auto node = m_VertexList.GetFirstElement();` because `m_VertexList` should be a class template. But you can add a `typedef` for the node to the list class and use that too:

```
template <typename T>
struct List
{
  typedef Node<T> node_type;
  typedef Node<T>* node_ptr_type;

  node_ptr_type GetFirstElement() { return first_; }

  node_ptr_type first_;
  ....
};
```

then

```
typedef List<Cobject> CObjectList
CObjectList l;
auto n0 = l.GetFirstElement();
CObjectList::node_ptr_type n1= l.GetFirstElement();
```

Once you're done with this exercise, you may want to look at `std::list` for an example of a well implemented doubly linked list class template.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is auto the only way though? Currently my renderer is trying to grab the data through more than just one layer, since vertices belongs to object.

TNode<CVertex*>* GetVertexList() const {return m_VertexList.First(); }

because you can't auto a function return type

I also heard not to rely on lists or vectors for the reason that they are unpredictable and not portable. I haven't heard so much bad things about list, but my tutors treat them the same

Comment: @Matt A) you can have auto return types, just look up "training return types", B) whoever told you not to rely on lists or vectors was surely joking. If you think you can implement something better, go ahead. But I seriously doubt it.

Comment: I think until a certain level they are relevant and extremely helpful. I still use them all the time, but for things like rendering I want to be in control of everything. A vector is definitely not what you want to use for that. Although I haven't heard anything bad about lists, I also see professionals implementing their own all the time, probably for portability, which is what I'm aiming for.
Cheers for the answer and further advice on training return types though, I will look into it :)